# General protection error, when i convert QString to Char

Tags: qt, qstring, general-protection-fault

I try to convert QString to const *char, it generate General Protection fault.
I could't understand about that.

[dmesg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWFjO.png)

[code that generate General Protection fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aYH7.png)

When I checked with gdb, segment fault is generated in "vfprintf".

[gdb result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCquh.png)

1. What does mean "General Protection"
2. I tried to run this code other system, it works well.
   Are there any conditions that could cause problems?

   1. redhat 6 / qt 4.6
   2. redhat 7 / qt 4.8

- I have already tried converting to "toStdString, toLocal8Bit, etc..."

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a moment to take our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, please avoid using pictures of code or error messages, and instead copy/paste the actual text into your post.

Comment: "General Protection Fault" is the name Intel assigned to the exception that happens when you try to use an invalid address.  Unix traditionally calls that a "segmentation fault".

Comment: Is that literally your code?  It shouldn't fail, but if you tried the shortcut `qstrputresult_path.toUtf8().constData()`, that CAN cause the result you see, because that returns a pointer to a temporary object that gets immediately destroyed.